# Why does the default value of a boolean variable tend to be false?

Tags: programming-languages, theory

As far as I'm aware, the default value of a boolean variable in C#, VB, Java and JavaScript is `false` (or perhaps "behaves like false" is more accurate in the case of JavaScript) and I'm sure there are many other languages in which this is the case.

I'm wondering why this is?  Why do language designers pick `false` for the default?  For numerical values, I can see that zero is a logical choice, but I don't see that `false` is any more a natural state than `true`.

And as an aside, are there any languages in which the default is true?

Comment: What are you basing the observation that "the default value for a boolean is false" on?

Comment: Other than my own experience, see Defaults in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx; Defaults in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html etc.

Comment: Adding to @deceze, you SHOULD initialize a boolean variable with **false** for **every** language..

Answer (score 5):

From the semantic point of view, boolean values represent a condition or a state. Many languages assume, if not initialized, that the condition is not met (or such state is empty, or whatever). It serves like a flag. Think about it on the other way around. If the default value for a boolean is true, then the semantics of that language would tell you that any condition is initially satisfied, which is illogical.

From the practical point of view, programming languages often internally store boolean values as a bit (0 for false, 1 for true), so the same rules for numeric types apply to booleans in this case.

Java's default value for boolean instance variables is always false, but that doesn't apply for local variables, you're required to initialize it.

Comment: I disagree that it is illogical; I can think of plenty of conditions that are initially satisfied (e.g.: am I alive?) and you only need to rephrase a variable to create a world in which every condition would be initially satisfied (e.g.: `HasBeenInitialised` vs. `NeedsToBeInitialised`).  I take your point about 0/1 internal storage though.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! there's a lot of possible conditions that make perfect sense to be initially true.

Comment: Not when programming. Nothing exists - until you make it exist.

Comment: Everything starts at zero. If you wanted a bool to init to true then you would need an additional operation to set a bit in to the bool. Path of least resistance is zero.