# why java boolean primitive has false as its default but not as true

Tags: java

Why boolean primitive in java takes false as default? why can't it take true as default? what is the rationale behind assigning certain specific values for primitives as their default values?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157180/why-does-the-default-value-of-a-boolean-variable-tend-to-be-false

Comment: Language design decision; enough said...

Comment: If it was 'true' you would be asking why it isn't 'false'. Some decision has to be made. It corresponds to zero and null.